# Equivalent of cheerio.load() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I know cheerio.load() will load the html into the `$` as below.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load('<ul id = "fruits">...</ul>');
```

Is there a way I can get the same `$` using raw jQuery?

Comment: Do you want use nodejs ?

Comment: I am only limited to client side for now so I unfortunately cannot use node js.

Comment: The value returned from `cheerio.load()` is a reference to the [`jQuery()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function, or at least [an equivalent of it](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#selectors). When used client-side, the jQuery library itself [defines `$` as a global alias](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#entry-longdesc).

Comment: `$ = $('#fruits');
$.querySelector(your css selector);
`

Comment: In this case you can get any element, or tag, or anything use jQuery!

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now that jQuery is just more verbose than Cheerio. Thanks for the answer guys.

Comment: Are you trying to work on the current document or on a string of HTML? If the latter, maybe [`parseHTML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/)?